# How to get access for specific plugin for Author role in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, user-permissions, redirection-wordpress-plugin, wordpress-capabilities

I need to apply for custom access for the WordPress Author role. I used the `$role->add_cap()` function in function.php and I need to get access to a specific plugin page Under the "Tools" section (To Redirection plugin).

If I used, `$role->remove_cap('manage_options');` it gives access to the whole section Tools and Settings. But need to get access only to the "Tools => Redirection" page. Any idea..?

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    $role = get_role( 'author' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_posts' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_pages' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_pages' );
    $role->remove_cap( 'manage_options' );
}
```

[image]